# VBA Excel/ Userform, Search function does not work

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Here is my Code:

```
Private Sub CmdSearch3_Click()

Dim FerNum As Variant, totRows As Long, i As Long

totRows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
FerNum = InputBox("Please enter the fermenter number you are looking for")

If FerNum = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the fermenter number you wish to search."
End If

For i = 2 To totRows
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value <> Trim(FerNum) And i = totRows Then
        MsgBox ("Sorry, the fermenter number " & FerNum & " is not found.")
    End If

    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = Trim(FerNum) And i = totRows Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter the data need here.")

        DTPickerActualHarvestDate.SetFocus
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
Exit Sub

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range
Set wks = Sheet1

Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

AddNew.Offset(i, 6).Value = DTPickerActualHarvestDate.Value
AddNew.Offset(i, 7).Value = txtpH.Text
AddNew.Offset(i, 8).Value = cboNumberofCases.Value

AddNew.Offset(i, 10).Value = cboNumberofPails2gal.Text

AddNew.Offset(i, 12).Value = cboNumberofPails5gal.Text

AddNew.Offset(i, 13).Value = txtRetailPouchWeight1.Text
AddNew.Offset(i, 14).Value = txtRetailPouchWeight2.Text
AddNew.Offset(i, 15).Value = txtRetailPouchWeight3.Text
AddNew.Offset(i, 16).Value = txt2galPailsWeight1.Text
AddNew.Offset(i, 17).Value = txt2galPailsWeight2.Text
AddNew.Offset(i, 18).Value = txt2galPailsWeight3.Text
AddNew.Offset(i, 19).Value = txt5galPailsWeight1.Text
AddNew.Offset(i, 20).Value = txt5galPailsWeight2.Text
AddNew.Offset(i, 21).Value = txt5galPailsWeight3.Text

Select Case cboTexture.Value
    Case Is = "Y"
        cboTexture.Value = "N"
    Case Is = "N"
End Select
AddNew.Offset(i, 22).Value = cboTexture.Text

Select Case cboFlavor.Value
    Case Is = "Y"
        cboFlavor.Value = "N"
    Case Is = "N"
End Select
AddNew.Offset(i, 23).Value = cboFlavor.Text

lstSearchResults.ColumnCount = 24
lstSearchResults.RowSource = "B1:AE65356"


End Sub
```

This code is for searching the fermenter number in the spreadsheet at the first step. When it is found, the user should be asked to input the data and the data will be entered into the spreadsheet corresponding to the fermenter number.

Right now the front part that examines if the messages box for entering fermenter number is Null is working. However even if the fermenter number exists in the spreadsheet, the system is still showing up the box that the number is not found. Therefore I can't test if the following code works.

Although I thought "Next i" should not follow after "Exit for" and " End if", it seems do not make sense. I tried to change the sequence of them, but It can only work in this case.

Could you please help me figure out how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that input boxes use strings and you want a number. The way around it is to convert the input to a number. Try:

```
Dim FerString As String
Dim FerNum as Long

FerString = InputBox("Please enter the fermenter number you are looking for")

If FerString = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the fermenter number you wish to search."
End If

FerNum = Val(FerSTring)
```

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you!

Comment: I solved that problem. Thanks a lot! For the next part, when the system has found the number and ask the user to input the data, how can those information be entered in the spreadsheet? It seems I lost some link between them.